# compare two arrays and copy unique element from second to first array VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, duplicates

I have two arrays: `TempSubject()`, which carries a list of subjects, and `friRoutine()`, which indicates when subjects are taught.

I need to enforce a rule that no particular subject can not be taught twice on a specific day. I have a function named `DetectDuplicate(friRoutine, Tempsubject(i))`, which checks `friRoutine()` with `TempSubject()` and finds whether `friRoutine` already contains a particular subject. If No, then add that unique subject to `friRoutine`. Otherwise continue through the loop for next subject. My code is furnished below as follows-

```vb
Dim TempSubject() As String = {"Maths","English","Sanskrit","Sanskrit","Urdu","Urdu","Urdu","French","French","French","Physical Education","Physical Education","Game","Game", "Science"}

dim c4 as integer = 0
dim limitcounter = 0
dim friRoutine() as string
reedim friRoutine(6)

While c4 < TempSubject.Length
    If DetectDuplicate(friRoutine, TempSubject(c4)) = False And limitcounter4 < 7 Then
        friRoutine(limitcounter4) = TempSubject(c4)
        'MessageBox.Show(c1 & ": " & limitcounter1 & ": " & tueRoutine(limitcounter1))
        Debug.WriteLine("Friday: " & c4 & ": " & limitcounter4 & ": " & friRoutine(limitcounter4))
        TempSubject.RemoveAt(c4)
        limitcounter4 = limitcounter4 + 1
    End If
    c4 = c4 + 1
End While


Private Function DetectDuplicate(ByVal arr As Array, ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Dim numcount As Integer = 0
    For numcount = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        If arr(numcount) = str Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

The Output is supposed to be

```
friRoutine = Math, english, sanskrit, Urdu, French, Physical education, game
```

but unfortunately, English is missing. 
the output is:

```
friRoutine = Math, sanskrit, Urdu, French, Physical education, game, science
```

I'm afraid of using my code as it may spoil the entire process at any point of time.
I think the problem is with Function  **DetectDuplicate()**

**Edit** (From a comment)

I have to remove the used elements. My original program will have 42 subjects and 6 days. 7 periods everyday. For example if i picked up 7 unique subjects for Monday then for the next 6 days i must have only 35 subjects to be adjusted for rest of the 5 days.

Comment: I'm sure we saw this question in the past couple of weeks, but I can't find it anywhere. Did you ask it before and delete it?

Comment: Can you just post the homework question here so we can understand the requirement?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would do is convert the arrays to generic Lists. So this:

```
Dim TempSubject() As String = {"Maths","English","Sanskrit","Sanskrit","Urdu","Urdu","Urdu","French","French","French","Physical Education","Physical Education","Game","Game", "Science"}
Dim friRoutine() As String
```

Becomes this:

```
Dim TempSubject As New List(Of String) From {"Maths","English","Sanskrit","Sanskrit","Urdu","Urdu","Urdu","French","French","French","Physical Education","Physical Education","Game","Game", "Science"}
Dim friRoutine As New List(Of String)(6)
```

You can access items in these lists by index, just like with arrays, but now it becomes *MUCH* easier to do things like add or remove entries. *At least*, I would do this for the `friRoutine` collection; there is some argument to made for an array in way `TempSubject` is used in this code, but even there the data likely came form somewhere that would justify a List(Of String) instead.

That done, you can **greatly** simplify the code:

```
friRoutine.AddRange(TempSubject)
friRoutine = friRoutine.Distinct().Take(7).ToList()
```

Or, to show the entire sample:

```
Dim TempSubject = {"Maths","English","Sanskrit","Sanskrit","Urdu","Urdu","Urdu","French","French","French","Physical Education","Physical Education","Game","Game", "Science"}

Dim friRoutine As New List(Of String)(TempSubject.Distinct().Take(7))
For i As Integer = 0 to friRoutine.Count - 1
    Debug.WriteLine($"Friday: {i} : {friRoutine(i)}")
Next
```

And now that we see the data for `friRoutine` can be computed from a single line of code, one wonders if we really need the separate collection at all.

As for the original code, the big problem was this line:

```
TempSubject.RemoveAt(c4)
```

This modified the collection while still looping through it. Everything would shift forward, causing some items to be skipped.

Comment: Props for picking up on the limit of 7 items

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Enumerable.Distinct<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

```vb
Dim TempSubject = {"Maths","English","Sanskrit","Sanskrit","Urdu","Urdu","Urdu","French","French","French","Physical Education","Physical Education","Game","Game", "Science"}

Dim friRoutine = TempSubject.Distinct().ToArray()
```

If you want a List output instead, then it's simply

```vb
Dim friRoutine = TempSubject.Distinct().ToList()
```

Since both array and List are Enumerable, `TempSubject` can be either an array or List.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn But i have to remove the used elements. My original program will have 42 subjects and 6 days. 7 periods everyday. For example if i picked up 7 unique subjects for Monday then for the next 6 days i must have only 35 subjects to be adjusted for rest of the 5 days.